# Removing Duplicates from an array in Python depending on the first 4 letters

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have a list of postcodes, e.g.

```
DD1 1DB
DD1 5PH
DD10 8JG
DD10 9LJ
```

What I would like to do is keep the first representative, depending on the first part of the postcode e.g.

I need to keep:

```
DD1 1DB
DD10 8JG
```

I am using pandas and imported the file.csv containing column POSTCODES as:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv')
pc = df.POSTCODES
```

Now I am completely stuck. I managed to get it working using Excel (is this the better option?) but I would like to learn python and decided to see if I can do it in python.

Comment: Please make an attempt.  If you do not need a Pandas DataFrame, you could easily do this with Python.  Check out [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) - practice the examples given, eventually you will start getting ideas for solving your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`df['POSTCODES'].str[:4]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) to obtain the first four characters,
and use the [`duplicated` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to identify duplicates:

```
In [89]: df.loc[~df['POSTCODES'].str[:4].duplicated(keep='first')]
Out[89]: 
  POSTCODES
0   DD1 1DB
2  DD10 8JG
```

Since `duplicated(keep='first')` marks duplicates as True, the row we wish to keep would be marked False. So to select the False rows with [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), the `~` is used to [invert the boolean Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Comment: What if you got up to `DD100` and `DD101`?

Comment: The OP requests a solution based on the first four letters. But I agree, splitting may be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
pc[~pc.POSTCODES.str.split(' ', expand=True)[0].duplicated()]
```

OR as piRSquared suggests in the comments:

```
pc[~pc.POSTCODES.str.split().str[0].duplicated()]
```

Output:

```
  POSTCODES
0   DD1 1DB
2  DD10 8JG
```

Comment: I like `pc[~pc.POSTCODES.str.split().str[0].duplicated()]`

Answer (score 0):

```
In[24]: f = '''\
   ...: DD1 1DB
   ...: DD1 5PH
   ...: DD10 8JG
   ...: DD10 9LJ'''.split('\n')
In[25]: d = {}
   ...: for line in f:
   ...:     left, right = line.split()
   ...:     if left not in d:
   ...:         d[left] = right
   ...: 
In[26]: d
Out[26]: {'DD1': '1DB', 'DD10': '8JG'}
```